# bash implement variable in a directory

Tags: bash, variables

I have a serial number: SX410-251509-0171

In my code I extract the 2 digit year (15 in example above) and the 2 digit week (09 in the example above) and want to use these in a file directory.

```
#! /bin/bash           

year=${serial:8:2}
week=${serial:10:2}
dir="/home/jbon/20$year/$week/$serial/run0/output_log"
echo $dir
```

When I run this code I'm getting the following output:

/run0/output_log015/09/SX410-251509-0171

I'm guessing the issue is around how I am using the variables in the string.

Comment: Do you actually want those `*` there? They seem odd. Are you running this through `bash` or through `sh` or `/bin/sh`?

Comment: Instead of writing _When I run this code I get a bad substitution_, please write the exact error message!

Comment: Now that you've included the _exact_ output, we can tell you what's wrong: your file has DOS end of lines: convert your file to unix format using, e.g., the `dos2unix` utility. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info especially the point **Check the example for common problems**.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are running the script with `sh`, not `bash`, and your `sh` links to a shell other than `bash` that doesn't recognize the substring expansion operator. However, you can rewrite it in a POSIX-compliant fashion:

```
yearweek=${serial##*AB}   # Drop everything up to and including AB
yearweek=${yearweek%%-*}  # Drop everything from - onward
year=${yearweek%??}       # Drop the two-digit week
week=${yearweek#??}       # Drop the two-digit year
```

Comment: He has `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: The error implies he's running the script with something like `sh script.sh`, so I'm just catering to the case where that is somehow required. Using `bash script.sh` or executing the script directly to take advantage of the hash bang would be better if possible.